# When range is range(x, x)

Tags: python

Looking for the rules for range when start and stop are equal, ie range(x, x).  Python documentation only shows rules for range(x, y) --at least that I could find.  I know it returns an empty list, but how does it behave in a for loop, for example:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print 'no'
            break
    else:
        print 'yes'
```

At n = 2, and x = 2, Python prints 'yes' when my intuition tells me it should print 'no' because 2 % 2 = 0.

edit: corrected i's to n's

Comment: Just to confirm: you want the `else` to be attached to the `for` and not the `if`, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  See Python tutorial 4.4

Comment: What is `Python tutorial 4.4` ?

Comment: It behaves the same, i.e. it still is empty.

Comment: Python tutorial 4.4 is The Python Tutorial section 4.4.  This code is a near replica of the code in that section.

Comment: The check `n % x == 0` is never performed for `n = 2` given that `range(2, 2)` gives an empty list.

Comment: If range is empty than `for` will not run.

Comment: Just checking :-) indentation problems are rampant on this site. For those not willing to google, [here is a link to the tutorial in question](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: Kinda new here, why the harsh down-voting.  Is it a stupid question?  My code is correct, nearly identical to Python documentation.

Comment: @Kevin at last someone answer correctly for my question `What is Python tutorial 4.4` :)

Comment: [This visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=for+n+in+range(2,+10)%3A%0A++++for+x+in+range(2,+n)%3A%0A++++++++if+n+%25+x+%3D%3D+0%3A%0A++++++++++++print+'no'%0A++++++++++++break%0A++++else%3A%0A++++++++print+'yes'++&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0) of the code as it executes may be useful.

Comment: @Kevin Oh, excellent!  I see now that it's a fairly obvious answer, but that tool is perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the "no" because

```
for x in range(2, n):
```

is not being executed.

This is because in range(2,2) there is no number!

```
>>> for i in range(2,2): print i
... 
>>>
```